# how to displaying the second and third record On View From Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am new in mvc

I want to displaying the 2 and 3 record?

now only displaying the first record I want to display 2 and 3 record?

student.cs

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Designaton { get; set; }

    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>() {
                    new Employee(){ Id=1, Name="Steve", Designaton = "hr" },
                    new Employee(){ Id=2, Name="Bill", Designaton = "finance" },
                    new Employee(){ Id=3, Name="Ram", Designaton = "hr" },
                    new Employee(){ Id=4, Name="Ron", Designaton = "finance" },
                    new Employee(){ Id=5, Name="Rob", Designaton = "finance" }
                };

            ViewBag.totalemp = emplist.Count();

            return View();
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";  
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<td>@((ViewBag.totalemp as IEnumerable<migrationdemo.Models.Employee>))</td>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.totalemp)
{
    @item.Id
    @item.Name
    @item.Designaton

}
```

I am facing below error

which place need to be changes

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQVIp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz8qI.png)

now only displaying one record I want to displaying 2 and 3,4,5 record also?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List<Employee>` in the `Index` method and set that to `ViewBag` and then iterate this in View.

Better solution will be to have a model class and return to View and use in the View.

Comment: I am facing convert type error please see this image which place I am doing mistake https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQVIp.png

Comment: the line should be `ViewBag.totalemp = emplist;` you need to assign not the count of list.

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but while starting code you need to get the basics right.

1. You have not declared a collection (Ex. Array/List)

   ```
   var employee = new Employee()
   {
       Id = 1,
       Name = "dmgrejory",
       Designaton = "HR"
   };
   new Employee()
   { 
       Id = 2,
       Name = "vinkos",
       Designaton = "Finance"
   };
   new Employee()
   {
       Id = 3,
       Name = "dmokls",
       Designaton = "Administrator"
   };
   ```

   Here **employee** variable will always hold only 1 object and that is the one with **Id = 1**

So try some sort of collection object for ex., [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) or [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1)

2. And then loop through your collection in view (Passed through viewbag)

@

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.employeelist)
{
    <div>
        @item.Id
        @item.Name
        @item.Designaton
    </div>
}
```

Tip: Always split larger problems in smaller ones and then solve one by one.

Comment: can you help more I am facing an error see this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQVIp.png

Comment: the line should be `ViewBag.totalemp = emplist;` you need to assign not the count of list.